# Is it possible to list all runtime dependencies for ROS

Tags: ros

I've read this link: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source and have known that the command `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic --simulate` can list all necessary dependencies of ROS on a clean system.

Also, I've read this link: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml

So I'm thinking if it is possible to list only the exec_depend of ROS?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not currently possible through official functionality.

There is an open PR on rosdep which is meant for this very feature. I have not tested it personally, but looking at the code changes, it seems to allow for rosdep functionality to act only on certain dependency types through the `--dependency-types` flag.

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/727